# Automatically set static routes between two networks without dhcp or default gateway

Tags: windows, group-policy, automation, static-routes

I have a windows domain network with two different subnets. Both are connected trough VPN gateways.

DHCP and default gateway is an exiting router blackbox. Unfortunately I have very limited control over it. It is not possible to add a route there or add such an DHCP option. So I need to teach all Computers (Domain Members) how to reach the remote net. A simple 'route add' would do the trick. But I want to set the route without touching each machine.

The closest idea I had would be a startup script deployed via GPO. It would add the routings to all remote networks except the local network. But I am not sure how to implement the logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an Active Directory site for each subnet, then using GPMC, you can deploy the computer startup script using a GPO attached to a site, rather than a GPO attached to an OU.

This will also work fine with laptop users that move between sites.

Answer (score 1):

Please remark this is not the easiest solution to what you asked but it will solve it the way I would prefer to work because I think having no or very limited control over your gateway and dhcp server (and possibly dns) is not very good.

In your case, if possible I would place a router/dhcp server in front of the blackbox and connect everything to it instead of connecting to the blackbox. Default gateway for the new router would be the blackbox and it would control everything so you would be able to send the routes directly from the dhcp options.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot physically rewire the network because it's a simple virtual LAN. Otherwise the tip is okay.